# Carrier name on Packing slip pdf in magento

Tags: php, magento

I don't have brief knowledge of magento, so I need some help for following issue:
I want to add carrier name on pdf of shipment, I got it in my code but I have not possible to show it on pdf which is downloaded.
 Some of my code is as follows:

```
$shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
$trackingNumbers = $getCarrier = '';
foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
    foreach ($shipment->getAllTracks() as $track) {
        $trackingNumbers = $track->getTrackNumber();
        $getCarrier = $track->getTitle();
    }
}
```

I want to show this name (which I got in $getCarrier variable) on pdf file, please help.
**Note:** My magento version is 1.9.0.1
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to know the file location which generates the pdf.If you are not aware of it then this file does that

> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment

Override this file and make changes here.

For further information on making changes of packaging slip pdf [this link](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/) may give you more idea.

Hope this will help.

Comment: If this works or helps don't forget to accept and voteup. This will help other too.

Comment: aton1004, can you please explain it in brief ? I don't have much more knowledge of magento I am new to it. Whatever link you provide from which I cant understand where to create the model (I mean path to create a model). Please help for that.
Actually I put this code in the shipment.php located at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/
From where I also added the barcode on pdf, after this I want to print this pdf like sticker size (10cm X 15cm). Is that possible ?

Comment: Actually in this link it overrides that file. For that please refer some tutorial on how to override a model,or something like that. Actually you don't need to do that,another way is to overwrite that file.Have a look http://linkwithnavin.blogspot.com/2014/11/easy-tips-if-overriding-core-magento.html .Copy the file as specified and you are ready to go